# Accessing Web Server URL in Virtual Environment from Mac Environment

Tags: web-services, virtual-machine

I am using Parallels to host my Windows 7 virtual environment in my Mac. I run a web service (ASMX) in Windows 7 environment and now I want to access that web service using my Mac. Is that possible?

Comment: What is the ip address of the mac?  can the mac reach the win7 vm? (ping for example). What happens when you enter http://11.211.55.3:1045/NotificationService.asmx on the VM?  What are your results for `netstat -na|find 1045` on the vm?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just access the service on the ip address/port of your (win7) virtual machine

Comment: I am using the following on Windows 7 machine and it does not pull anything: http://11.411.55.3:1045/NotificationService.asmx. 11.411.55.3 is the iPV4 address.

Comment: 11.411.55.3 is not a valid IPV4 address

Comment: That is what I get when I type ipconfig from the virtually hosted environment

Comment: No, it's not - max value for every art of the address is 255 (255.255.255.255)

Comment: I mean it is in the form of 11.411.55.3. the correct address is 11.211.55.3. But even then it does not pull anything when I subsitute it with the correct ip address.

Comment: ASP.NET server is running on port 1045.